# Are there tweaks to make Java less slow?

Tags: windows-7, performance, java

I am trying to do some modelling with Jude. It is slow! And by slow, I mean that when I am typing a name for an element, I have to stop and wait for the cursor to catch up, and I am a slow typist (30 wpm max). The model is yet very small too, so it isn't caused by too big a file.

This isn't a hardware problem, because the processor (core duo T9300) stays at about 20% and the RAM (2 GB) at about 50% usage.

So it could be that Jude is slow in itself. But I have the gut feeling that other Java applications feel somehow sluggish too. I know that Java isn't very performant, but this here is really bad. So I thought that maybe I've set a parameter in the JVM at some impossible value or such. Do you know how I could remedy that? Or at least, where to check if everything is all right (and how to recognize if it is all right)?

The OS is Windows 7, the Java version is jdk 1.6.0_20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue with NetBeans. [I used this site](http://developers.sun.com/docs/javacaps/installing/jcapsinstall.inst_increase_heap_size_t.html) as a starting point for making some changes. I couldn't really find anything specific to Jude, but I'm hoping it has a similar setup scheme. If that is the case, you could try allotting it more memory and see if that helps.

Comment: Sadly, this didn't help with Jude, as there is no such option in its configuration :(